# php oop some vague stuff

Tags: php, oop, object

Very quick question of php objects. so here is the code:

```
<?php
            class Person {
            public $isAlive = true;
            public $firstname, $lastname, $age;

       public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
           $this->firstname = $firstname;
           $this->lastname = $lastname;
           $this->age = $age;
       }
            }

        $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", "boring");
            echo $teacher->isAlive; 
        $student = new Person("Phil", "Kroupoderov", "20");
            echo $student->age;


         ?>
```

Where I'm echoing my age which should show 20, it is displaying 120 for some reason. Why is there a 1 and how to get rid of it?????

Comment: `true` is represented as an integer when output by PHP. So `echo $teacher->isAlive; ` prints `1` which comes before when you print the age.

Answer (score 0):

John Conde is correct.  You need to change this:

```
    $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", "boring");
        echo $teacher->isAlive; 
    $student = new Person("Phil", "Kroupoderov", "20");
        echo $student->age;
```

to this:

```
    $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", "boring");
        echo $teacher->isAlive."\n"; 
    $student = new Person("Phil", "Kroupoderov", "20");
        echo $student->age."\n";
```